# How to import or export elementor templates with media files in elementor, wordpress?

Tags: json, wordpress, templates, elementor

how to import JSON templates with images or media files?
then I export the template from elementor on one site and imported it to another site, template layout was good but no media show.

Answer (score 0):

You dont. It is 2022 and Elementor just made export an experimental function. Their terrible Export Kit also is crippled and will only export "all templates" and even fail at that by losing LottieAnimations and other stuff. It is just a terrible tool and the pro version is not worth the money.